# Tiny output on high voltage multiplier

Tags: high-voltage, troubleshooting

A DC voltage multiplier that I built uses a fly back transformer that outputs 15 mm arcs at a maximum (on its own.) When attached to the capacitor/diode multiplier circuit, it produces cm sized arcs between the first capacitor and a 1-2 mm size arcs between the multiplier output and ground. I expected 20-30 kV (from 2 stages.) It's almost like all the power is getting discharged across the first capacitor. When I insulate the first capacitor from arcing the output doesn't change. How would I fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the component list

1. Microwave oven transformer with 11 VAC output
2. full bridge rectifier
3. 1000 W ebay ZVS driver
4. Ebay flyback transformer
5. 1 nF 25 kV ceramic caps
6. 20 kV 2CL2FM diodes

I also tried using a switching power converter to drive the ZVS circuit as well as using different HV diodes with 9 stages, all with the similar effect of little to no output. I also tried other high voltage transformers like the 15kV arc igniter module on ebay with no success.

I suspect the ZVS driver because I switched out practically everything else at this point. Another potential failure point are the high voltage diodes, can I test these with a multimeter? It overloads my DMM in diode mode.

Interestingly, triggering an arc across the first capacitor on the high voltage side produces a more sizable arc at the output in a weird cascade effect.

Comment: Go [here](https://www.diyphysics.com/category/instrumentation/high-voltage-power-supply/).

Comment: I should add that it appears that DIY Physics has revised their website to remove many of the really good pictures. You can go to the [wayback machine to grab them](https://web.archive.org/web/20180303124615/http://www.diyphysics.com/2012/02/09/d-i-y-250-kv-high-voltage-dc-power-supply-with-neat-trick-for-switching-polarity/).

Comment: Thanks for the link but I still don't understand why my schematic doesn't work., or what to replace. The fly back transformer produces beautiful 0.5-1.5 cm long, high frequency AC arcs, so the flyback driver appears to work ok. Is the input power to low? Arcing the flyback draws 3.5 amps from the transformer secondary.

Comment: Lots of things pop to mind. Did you note the oil they use? In any case, all I can tell you is that when I'm careful and thorough I simply do NOT have problems working at voltages in the area you discuss. And I've been occasionally doing things like that (and much higher) over the years -- maybe five decades? When I had problems, it was always because of something stupid I had done and it usually only took me a short time to work it out.

Comment: @jonk I uploaded more pictures... I have since added a grounding wire with no change in behavior. My flyback works and according to DIY physics, any high freq AC works for this. My multiplier is wired normally, the capacitors are healthy. The diodes I got from Aliexpress, should I get new ones? How can I test them? What else am I missing?

Comment: [The datasheet](https://ppmpower.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/D-2CL2FM_REV_2.0.pdf) for your diodes says the they have a forward voltage of 35V.  Put 2k resistor in series with a diode and connect them to 40VDC. Measure the voltage across the diode. Reverse the diode and try again.  One way should be the full power supply voltage, the other should be 35V.